# Null pointer exception when refactoring the creation of an ArrayList of PGraphics from the main class into a separate class

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, pgraphics

I'm writing a Processing Applet in Java using Eclipse. I keep getting a null pointer exception when I refactor a method to create an ArrayList of PGraphics from the main class into a separate class. The method written all in the main class works (the first code sample below), it's the refactor that's not working (the second pair of code samples). I've searched all over for an answer (some similar but none match) and made numerous rewrites, but no dice. Take a look, and kind thanks in advance for your help:

This code (all in one class) works:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import processing.core.*;

public class GraphicsMain extends PApplet{
int screenWidth = 800;
int screenHeight = 500;
String filepath = "/a/filepath/here/";
ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray = new ArrayList<PGraphics>();
int stageWidth = 100; // eventually make this based on the motif's max width
int stageHeight = 400; // make this based on the motif's max height
PImage pic = loadImage(filepath + "small_jones6.png");
PImage pic2 = loadImage(filepath + "small_dresser10.png");


public void setup() {
    size(screenWidth,screenHeight,P3D);
    background(255);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        motifArray.add(createGraphics(stageWidth,stageHeight,P3D));
        motifArray.get(i).beginDraw();
        motifArray.get(i).image(pic,10,10,100,90);
        motifArray.get(i).image(pic2,10,50,50,50);
        motifArray.get(i).endDraw();            
    }

    if (motifArray.get(0) == null) {
        System.out.println("The motif array is unfilled!");
    }
}

public void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < motifArray.size(); i ++) {
        image(motifArray.get(i),200+(400*i),100);

    }

}

static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "GraphicsMain" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
        PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
}

}
```

This code below (refactored into two separate classes) does not:

** I've noted the two lines [one in each class] identified in the null pointer exception

Class 1:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import processing.core.*;

public class GraphicsMain extends PApplet{
int screenWidth = 800;
int screenHeight = 500;
PGraphicsMaker pgm = new PGraphicsMaker(this);
ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray;

public void setup() {
    size(screenWidth,screenHeight,P3D);
    background(255);

    motifArray = pgm.makeMotifArray(); // ** NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE **

    if (motifArray.get(0) == null) {
        System.out.println("The motif array is unfilled!");
    }
}

public void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < motifArray.size(); i ++) {
        image(motifArray.get(i),200+(400*i),100);

    }


}

static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "GraphicsMain" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
        PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
}

}
```

Class 2:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PGraphics;
import processing.core.PImage;
import processing.core.*;

public class PGraphicsMaker {
String filepath = "/a/filepath/here/";
PApplet parent;
int stageWidth = 100; // eventually make this based on the motif's max width
int stageHeight = 400; // make this based on the motif's max height
ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray;
PImage pic;
PImage pic2;

public PGraphicsMaker(PApplet pa) {
    PApplet parent = pa;
    pic = parent.loadImage(filepath + "small_jones6.png");
    pic2 = parent.loadImage(filepath + "small_dresser10.png");
}

public ArrayList makeMotifArray() {
    ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray = new ArrayList<PGraphics>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            // ** NULL POINTER EXCEPTION on the line below **
       motifArray.add(parent.createGraphics(stageWidth,stageHeight,parent.P3D));
       motifArray.get(i).beginDraw();
       motifArray.get(i).image(pic,10,10,100,90);
       motifArray.get(i).image(pic2,10,50,50,50);
       motifArray.get(i).endDraw();
    }
    return motifArray;
}
}
```

Any help would be fabulous. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor for `PGraphicsMaker`, you declare a local variable `parent` and assign `pa` to it.

```
PApplet parent = pa;
```

... when I'm sure you intended to assign it to the *instance variable* `parent`:

```
parent = pa;
```

In your code, the instance variable `parent` stays `null` until it's accessed, and a `NullPointerException` results.

Comment: Thanks---a simple mistake that's been eluding me for hours!